# Finding swap causes of MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, memory, buffer-pool

In my centos 6.3 server I have a MySQL 5.5.33 database.
It has 17 tables (15 InnoDB, 2 MyISAM) and total records 6.7M rows.
I refactored my schemas and added indexes for my slow logs. My average query time is 20-30 ms. And my database performs well.

But I have some cron queries that runs every 3 hours. They don't use any index, they runs very slow and every query runs nearly 1500-2000 ms. I don't plan to add new indexes for them, because in that case I have to add many indexes and that queries run very rare.

When I restart my database server, -normally- swap is zero. After some time swapping becomes large gradually. After 13 days, I get 650MB swap of MySQL. I want to find what causes this swapping and try to reduce the swap without performance grade.

I want to be sure that the cause is cron queries or some other thing causes this swap size.

My `top` results:

```
top - 13:33:01 up 13 days, 11:04,  1 user,  load average: 0.77, 1.02, 1.07
Tasks: 148 total,   1 running, 147 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 27.4%us,  5.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 59.1%id,  7.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1020564k total,   854184k used,   166380k free,    73040k buffers
Swap:  2097144k total,   643036k used,  1454108k free,    94000k cached

  PID USER        PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  SWAP COMMAND
 9573 mysql       20   0 2336m 328m 3668 S  7.3 33.0 349:14.25 554m mysqld
15347 examplecom  20   0  219m  32m  10m S  2.7  3.2   0:02.66    0 php-cgi
15343 examplecom  20   0  215m  28m  10m S 10.0  2.9   0:05.80    0 php-cgi
15348 examplecom  20   0  215m  28m  10m S 12.3  2.8   0:03.62    0 php-cgi
15346 examplecom  20   0  215m  28m  10m S  9.6  2.8   0:06.39    0 php-cgi
15350 examplecom  20   0  212m  25m  10m S 10.0  2.6   0:02.19    0 php-cgi
15345 examplecom  20   0  211m  24m  10m S  6.6  2.5   0:04.28    0 php-cgi
15349 examplecom  20   0  209m  22m  10m S  5.3  2.2   0:02.66    0 php-cgi
12771 apache      20   0  334m 5304 2396 S  0.0  0.5   0:02.53  10m httpd
12763 apache      20   0  335m 5224 2232 S  0.3  0.5   0:02.33  11m httpd
```

Edit: I restarted mysql server 2 days ago, so swap is low now. But with time passes it again will become bigger. When I make `top` I get this now:

```
top - 23:30:46 up 15 days, 21:01,  1 user,  load average: 0.35, 0.42, 0.42
Mem:   1020564k total,   931052k used,    89512k free,    76412k buffers
Swap:  2097144k total,   280528k used,  1816616k free,   233560k cached

  PID USER        PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  SWAP COMMAND
23088 mysql       20   0 1922m 311m 3440 S  1.0 31.3  50:04.53 143m mysqld
10081 examplecom  20   0  216m  28m  10m S  4.0  2.8   0:01.67    0 php-cgi
10069 examplecom  20   0  215m  27m  10m S  3.3  2.7   0:04.81    0 php-cgi
10070 examplecom  20   0  215m  26m  10m S  8.3  2.7   0:04.75    0 php-cgi
10062 examplecom  20   0  215m  26m  10m S  6.0  2.7   0:06.26    0 php-cgi
10060 examplecom  20   0  214m  25m  10m S  5.3  2.6   0:07.51    0 php-cgi
10074 examplecom  20   0  214m  25m  10m S  6.6  2.6   0:03.01    0 php-cgi
10080 examplecom  20   0  212m  23m  10m S  6.0  2.4   0:01.58    0 php-cgi
```

When I make `free -m` I get this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           996        927         68          0         76        219
-/+ buffers/cache:        631        364
Swap:         2047        273       1774
```

My `/etc/my.cnf` file contents:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
symbolic-links=0
skip-name-resolve

slow_query_log=ON
long_query_time=1.2

innodb_file_per_table

max_allowed_packet=32M
thread_stack=256K
max_allowed_packet=32M
thread_stack=256K
max_connect_errors=100000000
max_connections=600

key_buffer=256M
sort_buffer_size=2M
read_buffer_size=2M
read_rnd_buffer_size=2M

thread_cache_size = 8
tmp_table_size=128M
max_heap_table_size=128M
query_cache_size = 209715200
query_cache_limit = 52428800
join_buffer_size=4M
table_cache=2400
low_priority_updates=1
tmpdir = /var/tmp

query_cache_type = 1

innodb_buffer_pool_size=256M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=512K
innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
innodb_thread_concurrency=8

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: 1) How much RAM in the DB Server. 2) Please show all InnoDB settings in your `/etc/my.cnf`.

Comment: I will get the my.cnf, but how can I get the RAM in DB Server? Do you mean that my all RAM in server? or anything else?

Comment: Post the output of `free -m` to show how much RAM the DB Server has as well how much is free.

Comment: I edited question.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to over-allocate memory. You allow relatively large number of connections (600) along with larger session buffers (such as `tmp_table_size=128M, max_heap_table_size=128M`). So in worst case, when all the 600 parallel sessions use up the allowed 128M for `MEMORY` engine temporary tables, you need `600x128M= 77G` memory. But even with a `sort_buffer_size=2M` there is a need for 1.2GB, however you have 1GB only.

Having swap used is not a surprise this case. Check status variable `Max_used_connections` to see if use up to 600 connections, decrease the `max_connections` variable. Check status vars  `Created_tmp_disk_tables` and `Created_tmp_tables`, and you might safely decrease the `tmp_table_size` until `Created_tmp_disk_tables` is not increasing dramatically.

Also check whether kernel option `vm.swappiness` is not too high (such as 100), so that Linux starts swapping earlier, and more aggressively if getting out of memory